# WebUSB on Android Chrome

Tags: webusb

I have a website that connects to a label printer using WebUSB and prints labels. Everything works well on the computer, but unfortunately it does not work on Android. Android finds my printer "LP 433", but after nothing happens, it should print. I connect to the printer using the OTG cable. Google Chrome version: 83.
On other browsers WebUSB does not respond in any way, except firefox, it directly says that it does not support WebUSB. My site work on https.

```
  async findDevices() {
try {
  const navi: any = navigator;
  const devices = await navi.usb.getDevices();
  console.log(devices);
  devices.forEach(dev => {
    console.log(dev);
  });
  const device = await navi.usb.requestDevice({filters: [{vendorId: 15923}]});
  await device.open(); // Begin a session.
  await device.selectConfiguration(1); // Select configuration #1 for the device.
  await device.claimInterface(0); // Request exclusive control over interface #2.
  await device.controlTransferOut({
    requestType: 'vendor',
    recipient: 'interface',
    request: 0x01,  // vendor-specific request: enable channels
    value: 0x0013,  // 0b00010011 (channels 1, 2 and 5)
    index: 0x0001   // Interface 1 is the recipient
  })
    .then(() => device.transferIn(1, 64)) // Waiting for 64 bytes of data from endpoint #5.
    .then(result => {
      const decoder = new TextDecoder();
      console.log('Received: ' + decoder.decode(result.data));
      // document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = 'Received: ' + decoder.decode(result.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  const imgData: any = await this.toPrintFormat();
  for (let p = 0; p < this.pcs; p++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < imgData.length; i++) {
      //   setTimeout(() => {
      const string2 =
        'sLABEL,' + imgData[i].width + ',' + imgData[i].height + '\n' +
        'sGAP,0,0\n' +
        'sTPHY,0\n' +
        'sDENSITY,7\n' +
        'sSPEED,' + this.speedp + '\n' +
        'sTHERMAL,' + this.thermop + '\n' +
        'sDIRECTION,1\n' +
        'sORIGIN,0,0\n' +
        'wSAVEB64,' + imgData[i].src.length + ',\"WLP000\",' + imgData[i].src + '\n' +
        'wLOADIMG,0,' + 0 + ',1,\"WLP000\"\n' +
        'wPRINT,1\n';
      console.log(string2);
      const encoder = new TextEncoder();
      const data = encoder.encode(string2);
      device.transferOut(2, data)
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
  // document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = 'Received: ' + decoder.decode(result.data);
} catch (error) {
  // document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = error;
}
}
```

[image]
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Please include a link to the code that you are using and any error messages that appear on the console. You can use [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless) to set up remote debugging over WiFi since the USB port is in use. You can get debug logs from Chrome's interaction with the device from chrome://device-log.

Comment: @ReillyGrant Hello! I was hoping that you would see my question. Code and photos added :)

Comment: Can you add logging so we can determine where in the chain for `await` statements the code is getting to? Are there really no console errors printed? It might help debugging to append errors to a <div> on the page so that you don't need DevTools to inspect the state.

Comment: @ReillyGrant I decided to check how my site works on ubuntu and got the same thing. That is, the site connects to the printer, but the printer does not print. I opened the 'console log' and saw 'core.js: 6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Access denied' on the line 'await device.open ();'  it turns out that ubuntu does not allow to connect to the printer.

Comment: @ReillyGrant I found your article https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/build-for-webusb and made the rule 'SUBSYSTEM == "usb", ATTR {idVendor} == "3e33", ATTR { idProduct} == "0130", GROUP = "plugdev" ' and now there is a new problem in the console 'DOMException: Unable to claim interface.'

Comment: @ReillyGrant  if I choose a different claimInterface, I get a different error 'DOMException: The interface number provided is not supported by the device in its current configuration.'

Comment: @ReillyGrant on Android Chrome i get "NetworkError: Unable to claim interface"

Comment: @ИльяКузьмич hi where you able to solve this? looking to see an otg uvc cam on mobile chrome

Comment: @kristoph hello, at the first try changing vendorId to your own. Connect the device to OTG and see the vendorId at chrome:// device-log /

Comment: @ИльяКузьмич Did you manage to figure this out?